# I want to load Data Dynamically from SharePoint to Power BI as per user select title from existing visualization

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I want to load Data Dynamically from SharePoint to Power BI as per user select title from existing visualization.

I had already created one report, now i have to load data dynamically when client select title from existing visualization.

I tried to load table manually and combine them using append query but it got huge time.

I also searched for any REST API but not sucessed.